# Does it make sense to do a pool over a opengl buffer?

Tags: c++, opengl, memory

Let's say a scene can have up to 1024 point lights. Usually, there'd be less, but the worse case is 1024. They will be added and deleted dynamically over some time or after a certain action.

Does it make sense to allocate a uniform buffer with size `1024 * sizeof(PointLight)`, map the buffer at the beginning and do a pool over it? Or the better idea would be to create a CPU side pool and then commit the CPU side data to the buffer using `glNamedBufferSubData` every frame?

Something like this, very simple, does not take a uniform buffer alignment into consideration, because it's not related to the question.

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t MAX_SIZE>
    struct GPUPool
    {
        GPUPool()
        {
            glCreateBuffers(1, &ubo);
            glNamedBufferStorage(ubo, MAX_SIZE * sizeof(T), nullptr, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT);
            memory = (T*)glMapNamedBufferRange(ubo, 0, MAX_SIZE * sizeof(T), GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT);
        }

        ~GPUPool()
        {
            glDeleteBuffers(1, &ubo);
        }

        [[nodiscard]] inline uint32_t insert(const T& element)
        {
            if (!freeIndexes.empty()) {
                auto index = freeIndexes.back();
                freeIndexes.pop_back();

                memcpy(add(memory, index), &element, sizeof(element));

                ++size;

                return index;
            }

            memcpy(add(memory, backIndex), &element, sizeof(element));

            auto ret = backIndex;
            backIndex += sizeof(element);
            ++size;
            return ret;
        }

        void Bind(uint32_t bindingIndex)
        {
            glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bindingIndex);
        }

        void erase(size_t index)
        {
            freeIndexes.push_back(index);
            --size;
        }

        GLuint ubo = 0;
        T* memory = nullptr;

        std::vector<size_t> freeIndexes;
        uint32_t backIndex = 0;

        size_t size = 0;
    };
```

usage:

```cpp
struct PointLight
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 color;
    float fallof;
    float radius;
};


GPUPool<PointLight, 1024> pointLightPool;

std::vector<uint32_t> lightIndexes;

while(true) 
{    
    if(Something_Happend_And_Lights_Are_Added()) {
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            lightIndexes.emplace_back() = pointLightPool.insert(someLight);
    }

    if(Something_Happend_And_Light_2_And_5_Are_Deleted()) {
        //when lights get deleted, lightIndexes should also be updated, but let's leave it
        //for simplicity
        pointLightPool.erase(lightIndexes[1]);
        pointLightPool.erase(lightIndexes[4]);
    }

    if(Something_Happend_And_More_Lights_Are_Added()) {
        //light pool will place a new light into the old memory spot.
        lightIndexes.emplace_back() = pointLightPool.insert(someLight);
    }

    pointLightPool.Bind(0);
    //draw scene...
}
```

Comment: That is 32KB of data transferred per frame, that amount really does not matter at all. I would go with the simplest solution first - do away without a pool. Every frame just copy the active lights to the mapped buffer and draw.

Comment: yeah, but it's just a simple case I described. I been wondering if it does make sense to use that kind of pool ever.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "pool?" I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking whether it's better to map and unmap buffers vs. writing to them with `glBufferSubData()`?

Comment: The object pool pattern is a software creational design pattern that uses a set of initialized objects kept ready to use – a "pool" – rather than allocating and destroying them on demand. A client of the pool will request an object from the pool and perform operations on the returned object. When the client has finished, it returns the object to the pool rather than destroying it; this can be done manually or automatically.

Comment: It can be achieved using persistent mapping (as AZDO says) or using `glBufferSubData()` with the proper offset.